# Display UITextFields in subview depending on data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a somewhat specific task in my view now: I display some items on my view which may have a set of several properties. The view itself is just for one item. One of those items may have one or more sets of properties, which I want to display and/or offer the possibility for user input. 
I defined a xib for a set of properties which contains three UITextFields. Before it should be displayed, I load the data for the properties into an array. Then, depending on the length of the array, I would like to display the subview. 
At the moment, I try to do it it this way:

```
- (void) showSites:(NSArray *)sites hiddenMode:(BOOL)hidden
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < [sites count]; i++)
    {
        int h = 420 + i * 30;
        UIView *siteView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SiteView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.view addSubview:siteView];
        siteView.frame = CGRectMake(10, h, 760, 52);
    }
}
```

Unfortunatey this throws an NSUnkownKeyException with this reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key areaField.'  areaField is a UITextField, that I defined in the xib. It is also defined ion the heade file of the view class like that:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *areaField;
```

I am afraid, that after I solved this current problem, the next one will appear: How can I access the UITestfields for reading and/or editing...
Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: I know you said header file but still checking. Is it a protocol? Because properties in protocols are not automatically synthesized in its implementations.

Comment: No, it is definitely not a protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your text fields programatically like:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < [sites count] ; idx ++)
{

  UITextField *textField = [[UItextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 420 + idx * 30, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 25)];
  textField.tag = idx;
  textField.delegate = self;
  [self.view addSubview:textField];

}
```

Then you can access your textField by its tag, or its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, looks like ordinary buggy code to me...

problem 1: your method doesn't use the `sites` array. It only uses its count. i would regard this as a bug.

problem 2: the `hidden` parameter is also not used at all.

problem 3: it seems that your class is not prepared for being the "Files Owner" for these views. And I doubt that it should be. (how can multiple views bound different textfields to the same variable?)

problem 4: you have just one `UITextField` property but potentially an unbounded amount of text fields.

summary: the design of your code is broken, you have to redesign it from scratch.

Comment: Not really. I only showed parts of the whole method. Of cource I use the array later in this mwthod and also the hidden parameter! But they are not relöevant for the problem at all. That's why I didn't show the usage...

Comment: well, your question suggests that your method just contains one for loop. You should remove the closing brace to indicate that you only posted part of the code. problem 3 and 4 still apply though. You cannot be the files owner of multiple NIBs of the same type this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you've connected UITextField named areaField to IBOutlet property you can read/write it's content in respective ViewController with self.areaField.text

About your current problem, check connections in storyboard. Go to Connections Inspector and make sure referencing outlet has the same name as your outlet property in .h file.